# MySql query how to get first where date count is less than

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, recursive-query

## Goal

So my goal here is to have an sql query that returns the first date where there is no more than 5 records that respects the where clause(userId).

## Current schema

```
|id|user_id|scheduled_at|
|1 |1      |2023-03-16  |
|2 |1      |2023-03-15  |
|3 |3      |2023-03-15  |
|4 |1      |2023-03-15  |
|5 |1      |2023-03-15  |
```

## What have I achieved

```
    count(*) as cnt,
    scheduled_at
    from estudojo.user_scheduled_questions as uq where uq.user_id='1' and scheduled_at >=  '2023-03-14'
    group by scheduled_at
    having cnt < 5
    order by cnt ASC limit 1
```

The return is:

```
┌─────────┬─────┬─────────────────────────────┐
│ (index) │ cnt │        scheduled_at         │
├─────────┼─────┼─────────────────────────────┤
│    0    │  3  │ '2023-03-15'                │
└─────────┴─────┴─────────────────────────────┘
```

But still, not what I wanted, since the first date available is 2023-03-14

## Expect

I expected something like:

```
┌─────────┬─────┬─────────────────────────────┐
│ (index) │ cnt │        scheduled_at         │
├─────────┼─────┼─────────────────────────────┤
│    0    │  0  │ '2023-03-14'                │
└─────────┴─────┴─────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data has now row for this user on March 14th, so the query cannot return what you expect.

If you want the query to check over a fixed date range, then you would need to generate the range first, and then bring the table with a `left join`. In MySQL 8.0, we can do this with a recursive query:

```
with recursive all_dates as (
    select '2023-03-14' scheduled_at
    union all 
    select scheduled_at + interval 1 day from all_dates where scheduled_at < current_date
)
select ad.scheduled_at, count(uq.user_id) cnt
from all_dates as ad
left join estudojo.user_scheduled_questions as uq
    on uq.user_id = 1 and uq.scheduled_at = ad.scheduled_at
group by ad.scheduled_at
having count(uq.user_id) < 5
```

The recursive CTE generates all dates between March 14th and today (you might want to adjust the bounds) ; then, the outer query counts how many rows can be found in the source table for each date (and for a given user) - the rest is just aggregation and filtering with `having` (which you already had in your original query).

Note: if the dates in your table have a time portion, we would need to change the join condition to inequalities :

```
...
left join estudojo.user_scheduled_questions as uq
    on uq.user_id = 1 
    and uq.scheduled_at >= ad.scheduled_at
    and uq.scheduled_at <  ad.scheduled_at + interval 1 day
```